# Can't see state inside method helper function using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I cannot see the updated state inside of the helper method I'm using. All those worked in the class-based component, but it seems to be not the same when using hooks. Check out my comments.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';

import { VIMEO_URL } from '../../consts/urls';
import storage from '../../utils/localStorage';

const STORAGE_VIDEOS_DATA_KEY = 'VIDEOS_DATA';

import './VideoItem.scss';


const VideoItem = ({ vimeoId }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener(
      'beforeunload',
      saveStateToLocalStorage
    );

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener(
        'beforeunload',
        saveStateToLocalStorage
      );

      saveStateToLocalStorage();
    };
  }, []);


  const [ videoProgress, setVideoProgress ] = useState(0);

  const saveStateToLocalStorage = () => {
    const videosPlayedDuration = {
      [vimeoId]: videoProgress, // here I'm not getting updated videoProgress state, only default value
    };

    // here I will save videosPlayedDuration to the storage
  };

  return createPortal(
    <div className="video-modal-background" onClick={onVideoClose}>
      <div className="video-modal-window">
        <ReactPlayer
          playing={true}
          url={VIMEO_URL + vimeoId}
          onProgress={videoProgress => setVideoProgress(videoProgress.playedSeconds)} // here I'm setting state
        />
      </div>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('modal-root')
  );
};

export default VideoItem;
```

So the as you can see I'm trying to use updated state but all I'm getting there is 0 as a default state.

Comment: That's because your `useEffect` hook is only run once after the initial render, so the `saveStateToLocalStorage` reference inside of the function given to it will always be a reference to the `saveStateToLocalStorage` of the initial render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have `componentWillUnmount` behavior use [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) to access the updated values inside your listener:

```
   const [ videoProgress, setVideoProgress ] = useState(0);
   const videoProgressRef = useRef(videoProgress);
   useEffect(() => videoProgressRef.current = videoProgress, [videoProgress]);

   function saveStateToLocalStorage(){
      const videosPlayedDuration = {
        [vimeoId]: videoProgressRef.current, 
      };
   }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener(
      'beforeunload',
      saveStateToLocalStorage
    );

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener(
        'beforeunload',
        saveStateToLocalStorage
      );

      saveStateToLocalStorage();
    };
  }, []);
```

If you use `saveStateToLocalStorage` only inside `useEffect` it is better to move it inside the callback of `useEffect`. So it doesn't get recreated every render:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    function saveStateToLocalStorage(){
        const videosPlayedDuration = {
          [vimeoId]: videoProgressRef.current, 
        };
    }

    window.addEventListener(
      'beforeunload',
      saveStateToLocalStorage
    );

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener(
        'beforeunload',
        saveStateToLocalStorage
      );

      saveStateToLocalStorage();
    };
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused due to closure. Since the effect is run only on initial render, the listener holds reference of `saveStateToLocalStorage` which gets the state value from its closure only on initial render and hence the updated value isn't visible inside it.

You need to remove and add listener whenever the `videoProgress` state changes. In order to do that you can pass `videoProgress` as the second argument to `useEffect`

```
const VideoItem = ({ vimeoId }) => {
  const [ videoProgress, setVideoProgress ] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener(
      'beforeunload',
      saveStateToLocalStorage
    );

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener(
        'beforeunload',
        saveStateToLocalStorage
      );

      saveStateToLocalStorage();
    };
  }, [videoProgress]);


   function saveStateToLocalStorage(){
    const videosPlayedDuration = {
      [vimeoId]: videoProgress, 
    };

   };

  return createPortal(
    <div className="video-modal-background" onClick={onVideoClose}>
      <div className="video-modal-window">
        <ReactPlayer
          playing={true}
          url={VIMEO_URL + vimeoId}
          onProgress={videoProgress => setVideoProgress(videoProgress.playedSeconds)} // here I'm setting state
        />
      </div>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('modal-root')
  );
};

export default VideoItem;
```

Comment: There will be a `ReferenceError: saveStateToLocalStorage is not defined`, as you use it before its definition.

Comment: That is because function expressions are not hoisted. If you declare it as a function declaration, it will work

Comment: I guess you meant to write that `const` declarations are not hoisted.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I guess we are rendering a component too many times though. I only would like to fire useEffect on componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount. Now it saves to the storage every 1 second but I need to do that only when component mounts and unmounts.

Comment: @Murakami, Yes you are right, but it is recommended with react-hooks that when listeners use props or state values, they are recreated when the values change. You can check the details here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#explanation-why-effects-run-on-each-update

Comment: maybe you can use useMemo with vimeoId as a dependency to the function that create listener